# Return multiple sets of aggregated IDs from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Without using JQuery or other plugins I'd like to look for instances of matching attributes from an array of objects.

For example - in this array of objects there are two attributes that appear across more than one object (A and C with 3 and 2 values respectively).

The result format I'm after would be an array of arrays containing the IDs of the objects in question (see the result line). I've tried various types of filters but to no avail.

```
let data = [
  { id: 1, attribute: "A" },
  { id: 2, attribute: "b" },
  { id: 3, attribute: "C" },
  { id: 4, attribute: "A" },
  { id: 5, attribute: "e" },
  { id: 6, attribute: "C" },
  { id: 7, attribute: "g" },
  { id: 8, attribute: "h" },
  { id: 9, attribute: "A" }
];

let result = [
  [1, 4, 9],
  [3, 6]
];
```

Comment: kindly post the code which you have tried so far?

Comment: Do you just want the ids of 'A' and 'C'? How the result is generated is not clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use Array.reduce to make simple.

```js
let data = [
  { id: 1, attribute: "A" },
  { id: 2, attribute: "b" },
  { id: 3, attribute: "C" },
  { id: 4, attribute: "A" },
  { id: 5, attribute: "e" },
  { id: 6, attribute: "C" },
  { id: 7, attribute: "g" },
  { id: 8, attribute: "h" },
  { id: 9, attribute: "A" }
];

let result = [
  [1, 4, 9],
  [3, 6]
];
let results = data.reduce((x, {id, attribute}) => {
  if(!x[attribute]) x[attribute] = []
  x[attribute].push(id)
  return x
},{})
let finalResult = []
for( let key in results) {
  const value = results[key]
  if(value.length > 1) finalResult.push(value)
}
console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first use array `reduce()` method to group objects by `attribute` key and the get the required ids in a group like:

```js
let data = [
    {id:1, attribute:"A"}
  , {id:2, attribute:"b"}
  , {id:3, attribute:"C"}
  , {id:4, attribute:"A"}
  , {id:5, attribute:"e"}
  , {id:6, attribute:"C"}
  , {id:7, attribute:"g"}
  , {id:8, attribute:"h"}
  , {id:9, attribute:"A"}];

let result = Object.values(data.reduce((o, obj) => {
  o[obj.attribute] = (o[obj.attribute] || []).concat(obj);
  return o; 
}, {})).filter(({length}) => length>1).map(x=> x.map(({id}) => id));

console.log(result)
```